# How to declare multidimensional array VBA error: "Expected: expression"

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to create a multidimensional array. Per MSDN, I have the following:

```
Sub answersArray()
  Dim answers (,) As String
End Sub
```

This gives me the error "Expected: expression" and highlights the comma in the declaration statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently you found an [MSDN entry for VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you declare an array in VBA.

`Dim answers(5,5) As String`

would declare a 2-d array with bounds 0-5 and 0-5.

If you don't know the size at the time you dimension it, just use

`Dim answers() As string`

and then later you can use `ReDim()`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll do that.  Wasn't aware of the difference between VBA and VB.net

Comment: That are really only similar in syntax - fundamentally they are completely different languages.